# Prove that $\lim_{h\to\infty}(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a-b)}{r(a-b)+bh}) = \ln{a} - \ln{b}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I was playing around with some calculus, attempting to prove for myself:
$$\int_b^a{\frac{1}{x}} dx= \ln(a) -\ln(b)$$
However I came to a halt when the method I was using required me to prove the following:
$$\lim_{h\to\infty}\bigg(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a-b)}{r(a-b)+bh}\bigg) \equiv \ln(a) - \ln(b)$$
I am confident that they are equivalent, after testing a bunch of random values.

I don't want to use the fact that differentiation and integration are inverse operations. I am curious about how one would go about proving this (since I'm still at high school, so I haven't yet learned how to deal with difficult problems such as these)!

Comment: Something is not correct, as the sum diverges (by the limit comparison test).

Comment: You can show us how you tested random values, and then we may find out where is the mistake.

Comment: I fixed the error in my question already. I tested $a = e^9$ and $b = e^5$ which returned the value 4, which is correct unless I did something dumb.

Comment: @Syba The sum is a big O of harmonic series, i.e. it's divergent. How do you calculate it?

Comment: Using an online calculator - symbolab:
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/series-calculator/simplify%20%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(a-b%5Cright)%7D%7Bn%5Cleft(a-b%5Cright)%2Bbx%7D%5Cright)%5Cright)

Comment: Note that the calculator's sum is from 0 to $x$...

Comment: And what is x? Doesn't it work if x is tending towards $\infty$

Comment: The usual definition of the logarithm is $\ln{x}=\int_1^xt\,\mathrm{dt}$ which of course makes what you want to prove trivial, so I must ask, what definition of the logarithm are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think using a series to get to the logarithm won't get you very far.

In fact we'd rather calculate such series as a Riemann sum leading to integration of $\frac 1r$ and giving $\ln$ as a result.

Instead it is possible to play with the properties of the integral.

Let set $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}t$

- One possibility would be to assume some knowledge on exponential function and show $f$ is its inverse.

For instance substitute $t=e^u$ then $$f(e^\alpha)=\int_1^{e^\alpha}\dfrac{dt}{t}=\int_0^\alpha \dfrac{e^u\mathop{du}}{e^u}=\int_0^\alpha du=\alpha$$

- Another possibility is to find the morphism formula associated to the logarithm.

First by substituting $u=\frac 1t$ then $$f(\frac 1x)=\int_1^{\frac 1x}\dfrac{dt}{t}=\int_1^x \dfrac{-u\mathop{du}}{u^2}=-\int_1^x du=-f(x)$$

Then by substituting $t=bu$ then 
$$f(ab)=\int_1^{ab}\dfrac{dt}{t}=\int_{\frac 1b}^a \dfrac{b\mathop{du}}{bu}=\int_{\frac 1b}^a \dfrac{du}{u}=f(a)-f(\frac 1b)=f(a)+f(b)$$