# Finding out the integral of 1/x by calculating the area

Tags: integration

Basic understanding of integration is to calculate the area between a function and the x-axis. If you want to calculate the area from 0 to x, you will slice the area to n parts and add up them.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n f \left ( \frac{ix}{n} \right ) \, \frac{x}{n}
$$

So the area of 1/x from 0 to x will be:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n f \left ( \frac{ix}{n} \right ) \, \frac{x}{n} & = \left ( f \left ( \frac{1x}{n} \right ) + f \left ( \frac{2x}{n} \right ) + \cdots + f \left ( \frac{nx}{n} \right ) \right ) \frac{x}{n} \\
& = \left ( \frac{n}{x} + \frac{n}{2x} + \cdots + \frac{n}{nx} \right ) \frac{x}{n} \\
& = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
$$

x disappeared. But the area of 1/x obviously depends on x.
So I'm confused with this and want an explanation about how to understand this.

By the way, I do know that

$$\int {1\over x}{\rm d}x=\ln|x|+C$$

and there are ways to get this without calculating the area. But I want to solve the question about the area of 1/x.

Comment: Are you talking about the integral $\int_0^x\frac1t\,\mathrm dt$?

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about it.

Comment: It is equal to $\infty$. Therefore, no, its does *not* depend on $x$.

Comment: Oh! I see. That makes senese. Thank you!

Comment: Apart from the fact that your integral diverges , I think it might be useful to consider the exponential function and how functional inverses affect integrals. You can find the log term like this

Comment: Thank you for the advise. But unfortunately I'm not smart enough to understand your point. It would be nice, if you kindly tell me a little more detail.

Comment: You might be interested in this result which holds for $x>0$...

$$\ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac {dt}t$$

$$= \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x-1}{N +n (x-1) } $$

Comment: Thank you. I'm feeling that I need to think well about the definition of ln and ln(0) is undefined.

Comment: You might be interested in this video by Mathologer https://youtube.com/watch?v=G0Fa5Zl-Z3c for the geometrical aspect of the logarithms. As for showing $\int \frac 1t dt$ verify the multiplicative to additive property I've done it here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3299124/399263

Comment: It was quite interesting. Thank you!